glitch like fluctuation in Sonner Toast ( react.js )
I am using sonner in order to make toast messages in react.js it's working fine but in one specific computer it is causing fluctuation like when I am hovering over it is blinking and causing disruption
I want this issue to get resolve so that I can more
